# My Windows 10 Computer Seems to Wake up And Run Slower

Tags: windows-10, performance, sleep

I've got a beefy Windows 10 desktop computer (specs below) that has a NVidia 970 card, two 4K monitors and bunch of bluetooth devices (k/b, mice, etc.).  I've noticed that once it has gone to sleep and woken up, everything seems like it is dragging. Things like gmail take longer to load, typing feels a little like typing in sludge (not horrible but noticeable).

When I look in task manager, my CPU is showing 1% usage, memory is also barely used.

Any hints where to look?

[image: PC specs]

Comment: Does the performance improve after a while or does it remain this way until a reboot?

Comment: Stays the same, at least 30 minutes and then I get frustrated and reboot usually

Comment: Is it possibly to test with a wired keyboard/mouse rather than the bluetooth ones?

Comment: wired or non-wired k/b and mouse is the same.  I can visibly see things updating slower on the screen.  an obvious example is the scrollbar that shows when gmail is loading emails.  I have a macbook on my desk also running parallels and I can launch gmail on that while the desktop is still loading.  Also odd, is I've noticed Visual Studio launches super slowly (like 10x slower).  I've got a super fast SSD also.

Comment: What seems the most odd is that nothing shows up in taskmanager.  when my system is booting, taskmanager shows all the apps slowly settling in and eventually goes to 0 to 1% as I expect but the computer stays slow.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Standby/Resume**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This suspends the device and resumes it. Now you have 2 minutes to do some operations which are slow. All activity gets logged into an ETL file.Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.I'll look at it

Comment: I took the computer back to the store that assembled and it and they found that an ASUS Fan Controller Driver was causing the problem. They updated that driver and now performance is what I expect when it comes out of sleep.  No idea how they figured this out but it appears to have solved the problem.  Makes me like macs even more.

Comment: ok, post this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the computer back to the store that assembled and it and they found that an ASUS Fan Controller Driver was causing the problem. They updated that driver and now performance is what I expect when it comes out of sleep. No idea how they figured this out but it appears to have solved the problem. Makes me like macs even more.